# LINQ query for the following

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Could someone help formulate a LINQ query for the following problem.
I have the following list of Key-Value number sets (mind that Duplicate Keys are allowed). There are thousands of such sets.

```
{4,3}, {4,1}, {4,8}, {4,9}, {2,3}, {4,9}, {3,1} , {3,4}
```

What data structure would suit me best.
Also, I want to group the above list of key-pairs, and OrderByDescending() so that i can extract the highest Key-Value pair of a Key-group.

For example in the above case, expected output:

```
{4,9}, {4,9}, {4, 8}, {4, 3}, {4, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 1}
```

Thanks

Comment: "What data structure would suit me best."- what operations do you need and what are your performance requirements?

Comment: am not too finicky abt performance.
as for operational requirements, i would like it to be something like LookUp, so that LINQ operations are extensible.

Comment: @aromore I bet your clients are.

Comment: Can you better define your "ordering" logic?  Your example is neither ordered by the fist item nor the sum of the two items.

Comment: it is "grouped by" the key item...and "thenOrderedBy" the value item (meaning...the kvps are ordered by the values "after" they have been grouped)...

Comment: So why does `{4,1}` come before `{2,3}` which comes before `{3,4}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
input.OrderByDescending(p => p.Key).ThenByDescending(p => p.Value);
```

or

```
input.OrderByDescending(p => new { p.Key, p.Value });
```

Answer (score 1):

Either a custom class with two values or a `Tuple<int, int>` would fit the needs you list.

To group, you can either use `Tuple<int, int>` directly and define an `IComparer<Tuple<int,int>>`  or inherit from `Tuple<int, int>` and implement `IComparable<Tuple<int,int>>` with that class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx). It represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var largestPair = list.OrderByDescending(z => z[0]).ThenByDecending(z => z[1]).First();
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", largestPair[0], largestPair[1]);
```